# Let $f_n(x) = (x-\frac{1}{n})^2$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

Does the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converge pointwise in the set $[0,1]$?

And the question asks to give the limit function as well.

So far I have:

$$f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$$
$$f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(x^2-\frac{2x}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})$$
$$f(x)=x^2 \;\forall x\in[0,1]$$
I am stuck from here

Comment: Why do you say you are stuck? What do you think the end result should look like?

Comment: @311411 I am not sure if what I have shown is the limit function or not, I think it may need an epsilon delta proof of the limit

Comment: Since $0\le x\le 1$, $$
\left| {f_n (x) - f(x)} \right| = \left| { - \frac{{2x}}{n} + \frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right| \le \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{{n^2 }} \le \frac{3}{n}.
$$ Can you finish from here?

Comment: @Gary And I think then I should choose $n=\frac{3}{\epsilon}$, is that the end of the question?

Comment: More precisely, take $n_0 : = \left\lceil {3/\varepsilon } \right\rceil$ and assume $n\ge n_0$.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant N as thats what I had n>N set to. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct and indeed $f_{n}\to x^{2}$ pointwise on $[0,1]$.

The definition of *pointwise convergence* of a sequence of functions $(f_{n}(x))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ on a set $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ says, $f_{n}\to f$ pointwise on $I$ if, and only if,
$$(\color{red}{\forall x\in I})(\forall \varepsilon >0)(\color{red}{\exists N\in \mathbb{N}})(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})(n>N\implies |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon.$$

Let the sequence of functions $f_{n}(x)=\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2}$ and let's to show that $f_{n}\to f$ pointwise on $[0,1]$, with $f(x)=x^{2}$.

Let $x\in [0,1]$ and let $\varepsilon >0$. By the Archimedean property
there exists a natural number $N>\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$. If $n>N$ we have
\begin{align*}
|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|&=\left|\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2}-x^{2}\right|\\&=\left|x^{2}-\frac{2x}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}-x^{2}\right|\\ &\leqslant \frac{|2x|}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}},\quad 0\leqslant  x\leqslant 1,\\&\leqslant \frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\\&\leqslant \frac{3}{n},\\&<3\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\right),\\&=\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Therefore $f_{n}\to f$ pointwise on $[0,1]$.

Moreover $f_{n}\rightrightarrows f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

The definition of *uniform convegence* of a sequence of functions $(f_{n}(x))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ on a set $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ says, $f_{n}\rightrightarrows f$ uniformly  on $I$ if, and only if,
$$(\forall \varepsilon >0)(\color{red}{\exists N\in \mathbb{N}})(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})(\color{red}{\forall x\in I})(n>N\implies |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon.$$

Let the sequence of functions $f_{n}(x)=\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2}$ and let's to show that $f_{n}\rightrightarrows f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$, with $f(x)=x^{2}$.

Let $\varepsilon >0$, thus choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N^{2}}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $\frac{2x}{N}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Thus for all $n>N$ we have
\begin{align*}
|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|&=\left|\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2}-x^{2}\right|,\\&=\left|-\frac{2x}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right|,\\&\leqslant \frac{2x}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}},\\&<\frac{2x}{N}+\frac{1}{N^{2}},\\&=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\\&=\varepsilon.
\end{align*}

Therefore $f_{n}\rightrightarrows f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Alternatively notice that
$$\sup_{x\in [0,1]}\left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\right|\to 0,\quad n\to +\infty$$
Therefore $f_{n}\rightrightarrows  f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$. Then also $(f_{n}(x))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniform Cauchy.